# Using current macro in linux kernel

Tags: c, linux-kernel

I am changing the kernel in linux using C. I have to include information about a process and test it. This is being done on a vm. I have updated the kernel to 5.1. In my home directory I have the source code for 5.1. I have to go into the file in the 5.1 folder and type the information in /kernel/sys.c. My question is in order to use the current macro do I need to have an include statement both in the test file and in the /kernel/sys.c file as well? Also would I include it using

`#include <include/asm/current.h>`

because the actual header file in the linux-5.1 folder is found in

`include/asm-generic/current.h`

so would I need the `#include` statement in the kernel/sys.c file and would it be

`#include <include/asm-generic/current.h>` or `#include <include/asm/current.h>`

Comment: *asm-generic* is a meta-folder, which replaces missed parts of architecture dependent headers. So, it's a very rare cases when you need to include something directly from *asm-generic*.

Comment: @0andriy: yes, but I do not have an `include/asm` folder. Does that mean I do not need an `#include` statement?

Comment: Again, *asm* is the architecture dependent one and of course you have it. In the case where no such folder (there is no architecture with a such in Linux kernel IIRC), build system makes it for you. Needs of the included header in the code is solely decision based on the code, developer should do a right choice.